# How to send data from AppDelegate to my subclass of ViewController in swift 4

Tags: uiviewcontroller, appdelegate, swift4.1

I am using Swift 4.1 and I am wondering how to pass the url data that is given here:

```
func application(_ app: UIApplication, open url: URL,
                    options: [UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey : Any]) -> Bool {
}
```

into my subclass of UIViewController I called HotSpotRISViewController. Here is what I attempted:

```
func application(_ app: UIApplication, open url: URL,
                    options: [UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey : Any]) -> Bool {
    self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
    let vc = HotSpotRISViewController()
    vc.setURL(theURL: url)
    let navigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: vc)
    self.window!.rootViewController = navigationController

}
```

My HotSpotRISViewController contains this function:

```
func setURL(theURL: URL) {
    self.url = theURL
    print(self.url ?? "nil")
}
```

Inside my HotSpotRISViewController I have a property of type URL ready to be set. The above code correctly passes the info, because my print statement prints out the URL, but I get a black screen instead of my app. What am I missing? And then on the other hand, the following makes the app start up correctly but I have no idea how to pass the url data using this method:

```
func application(_ app: UIApplication, open url: URL,
                    options: [UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey : Any]) -> Bool {
    let mainStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let initialViewController = mainStoryboard.instantiateInitialViewController()
    self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
    self.window?.rootViewController = initialViewController
    self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
}
```

I'm wondering how I can get both my app started up correctly without a black screen and pass the url data. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

You can add a global variable in your appDelegate file and fetch it with your setURL function :

**In your AppDelegate.swift**

```
    var myurl: URL!
    ....

    func application(_ app: UIApplication, open url: URL,
                options: [UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey : Any]) -> Bool {
        self.myurl = url
        let mainStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let initialViewController = mainStoryboard.instantiateInitialViewController()
        self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
        self.window?.rootViewController = initialViewController
        self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
    }
    ...
```

**In your HotSpotRISViewController.swift**

```
func setURL(theURL: URL) {
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        if let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate {
            self.url = appDelegate.myurl
        }
    }
```

Comment: Where do I make a call to func setURL(theURL: URL)?

Comment: Actually, I ended up putting this in my AppDelegate: `var vc = HotSpotRISViewController()` and then I just did this: `func application(_ app: UIApplication, open url: URL,
                        options: [UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey : Any]) -> Bool {
        vc.setURL(theURL: url)
        return true
    }` and it works. However, I am curious about your way. And I would like to know why you used `DispatchQueue.main.async`

Comment: sorry about the DispatchQueue.main.async. You don't need it in your situation. I had it in there because of how I used it.

Comment: Adam, could you figure out why you got the black screen ?